LazyIntializeException everywhere after configuring database manually by DataSource bean
I made all project with open session in view set to true, now I needed to add a new database to project it leads to configure my old datasource manually as follows (before then it was configured on application.properties):
@DependsOn("assinanteContext")
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "org.crm", // Adjusted package for primary repositories
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "mainEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "mainTransactionManager",
        excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(
                type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, classes = {
                AssinanteRepository.class
        }
        )
)
public class DataSourceConfig {

    @Autowired
    private AssinanteContext assinanteContext;

    @Value("${app.assinante-cnpj}")
    private String cnpj;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        HikariConfig hikariConfig = new HikariConfig();
        hikariConfig.setJdbcUrl(assinanteContext.dbURL);
        hikariConfig.setUsername(assinanteContext.dbUser);
        hikariConfig.setPassword(assinanteContext.dbPass);

        hikariConfig.setConnectionTestQuery("SELECT 1");
        hikariConfig.setValidationTimeout(3000);
        hikariConfig.setIdleTimeout(60000);
        hikariConfig.setMaxLifetime(1800000);
        hikariConfig.setMinimumIdle(5);
        hikariConfig.setMaximumPoolSize(20);

        return new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig);
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean mainEntityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factory.setPackagesToScan("org.crm"); // Main packages to scan
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.physical_naming_strategy", "org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy");
        properties.put("hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy", "org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy");
        factory.setJpaProperties(properties);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager mainTransactionManager(EntityManagerFactory mainEntityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(mainEntityManagerFactory);
    }
}


The problem is I'm getting lazyInitializationException on whole application,
even with warn
WARN 13764 --- [  restartedMain] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default.
I know I can use @Transactional Hibernate.initialize EAGER but all project was working well before manually configuring Datasource, it is not worth reconfigure 100 files of related entities in order to solve that, I really think OSIV was broken
StackTrace
2024-10-22T08:39:12.714-03:00  INFO 9396 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 9999 (http)
2024-10-22T08:39:12.746-03:00  INFO 9396 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2024-10-22T08:39:12.747-03:00  INFO 9396 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.10]
2024-10-22T08:39:13.082-03:00  INFO 9396 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2024-10-22T08:39:13.103-03:00  INFO 9396 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 6929 ms
2024-10-22T08:39:13.404-03:00  INFO 9396 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2024-10-22T08:39:14.844-03:00  INFO 9396 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@3d7bfecd
2024-10-22T08:39:14.847-03:00  INFO 9396 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2024-10-22T08:39:14.993-03:00  INFO 9396 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2024-10-22T08:39:15.126-03:00  INFO 9396 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.2.5.Final
2024-10-22T08:39:15.130-03:00  INFO 9396 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000406: Using bytecode reflection optimizer
2024-10-22T08:39:15.932-03:00  INFO 9396 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.b.i.BytecodeProviderInitiator        : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : bytebuddy
2024-10-22T08:39:16.470-03:00  INFO 9396 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.o.j.p.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo      : No LoadTimeWeaver setup: ignoring JPA class transformer
2024-10-22T08:39:17.535-03:00  INFO 9396 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.b.i.BytecodeProviderInitiator        : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : bytebuddy
2024-10-22T08:39:19.925-03:00  INFO 9396 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2024-10-22T08:39:19.929-03:00  INFO 9396 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2024-10-22T08:39:24.555-03:00  INFO 9396 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-2 - Starting...
2024-10-22T08:39:25.149-03:00  INFO 9396 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-2 - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@40a952b4
2024-10-22T08:39:25.149-03:00  INFO 9396 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-2 - Start completed.
2024-10-22T08:39:25.166-03:00  INFO 9396 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2024-10-22T08:39:25.459-03:00  INFO 9396 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.b.i.BytecodeProviderInitiator        : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : bytebuddy
2024-10-22T08:39:25.459-03:00  INFO 9396 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.o.j.p.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo      : No LoadTimeWeaver setup: ignoring JPA class transformer
2024-10-22T08:39:25.951-03:00  INFO 9396 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.b.i.BytecodeProviderInitiator        : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : bytebuddy
2024-10-22T08:39:27.015-03:00  INFO 9396 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2024-10-22T08:39:27.015-03:00  INFO 9396 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2024-10-22T08:39:27.409-03:00  INFO 9396 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.j.r.query.QueryEnhancerFactory     : Hibernate is in classpath; If applicable, HQL parser will be used.
Bulk cadastro ignorado
2024-10-22T08:39:36.345-03:00  INFO 9396 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@2ab894df, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@29bdd752, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@7950e457, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@372bbf0c, org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter@9cf28ff, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@7bfad9fd, org.crm.infra.auth.SecurityFilter@3c0b8c94, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@4e57324b, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@6745f5e3, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@74142e4e, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@3d9a28ac, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@3d975834, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@3306101a]
2024-10-22T08:39:37.181-03:00  INFO 9396 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 9999 (http) with context path ''
2024-10-22T08:39:37.184-03:00  INFO 9396 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.m.s.b.SimpleBrokerMessageHandler     : Starting...
2024-10-22T08:39:37.190-03:00  INFO 9396 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.m.s.b.SimpleBrokerMessageHandler     : BrokerAvailabilityEvent[available=true, SimpleBrokerMessageHandler [org.springframework.messaging.simp.broker.DefaultSubscriptionRegistry@4458818d]]
2024-10-22T08:39:37.191-03:00  INFO 9396 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.m.s.b.SimpleBrokerMessageHandler     : Started.
2024-10-22T08:39:37.212-03:00  INFO 9396 --- [  restartedMain] org.crm.CRMSpringBootApplication         : Started CRMSpringBootApplication in 32.268 seconds (process running for 34.81)


Please share also the stack trace when running the application.

The error here is relying on Open Session In View which is considered an anti-pattern. That being said if you want this you will need to enable it yourself as it will only work with auto-configuration. you started to do manually configure JPA which will let this backoff.

Project is tested and working well with osiv, but after manually config datasource it got broken, I really need it, the application was made with osiv in mind, refactoring the app to not return LazyLoadException without osiv would take months

I tried to add osiv beans to DataSource but got nothing, I hardly need it

Added a bean configuration regarding the mainEntityManagerFactory():
@Configuration
public class OsivConfig {
    @Bean
    public OpenSessionInViewFilter openSessionInViewFilter() {
        OpenSessionInViewFilter filter = new OpenSessionInViewFilter();
        filter.setSessionFactoryBeanName("mainEntityManagerFactory");
        return filter;
    }
}

